# Convert a decimal time representation to unix epoch

Tags: c, unix

I have a time stored in a 64 bit int of the form 20110103101419 (i.e. representing 2011-01-03 10:14:19). How do I convert that to seconds since 1970 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My C is a bit rusty, but looking at the other two answers I would write a function as follows, returning the number of seconds since epoch or -1 in case of error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t convertDecimalTime(long dt) {
  struct tm time_str;

  time_str.tm_isdst = -1;
  time_str.tm_sec   = dt%100; dt/=100;
  time_str.tm_min   = dt%100; dt/=100;
  time_str.tm_hour  = dt%100; dt/=100;
  time_str.tm_mday  = dt%100; dt/=100;
  time_str.tm_mon   = dt%100-1; dt/=100;
  time_str.tm_year  = dt%10000 - 1900;

  return mktime(&time_str);
}
```

Comment: The page I linked has a complete example ;)

Comment: Close, but you need to subtract 1 from `tm_mon`: Months are 0-based: 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) . You can parse the intput and use %s format to display the number of seconds since the Epoch,

Comment: Well, the question then is How to parse the input(e.g. 20110103101419 ) to a time_t (or struct tm) , which is really what I asked in the first place.

Comment: You can parse the input string and then use mktime

Comment: And again, that is the question *how to parse* (note, my date is NOT a string it's a long long, so not suitable to pass to strftime in the first place). ivy showd me how to parse it though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mktime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html) to create a `struct tm` then you can use `strftime` with `%s` format parameter to get number of seconds since the epoch.